# Table not showing dynamically after click on tab, only after clicking anywhere on webpage it shows

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, servlets

So in summary, I'm using JSP's for view and servlets to do all my processing of data. JQuery .ajax function is being used to get data from a servlet on server side. All works well.

On one page I'm using JQuery UI Tabs.

When the page loads, it loads the tabs and pages correctly. but on the second tab i have a html table which is dynamically updated via data from a servlet.

So:
Clicking on Tab:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#tabs-2").click( function()
       $.ajax(
                                    {
                                        url:'URLTOSERVLET',
                                        type:"GET",
                                        async:true,
                                        success:function(data)
                                        { 
                                            $("#myTable").html(data);

                                        }
                                    });
    });
});
```

The Div which the output from ajax (Data) should be put in:

```
<div id="myTable">                          
</div>
```

And the output data is in the basic table format example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  data
</td>
<td>
  data
</td>
<td>
  data
</td>
<td>
  data
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

now where my problem lies is that after clicking on the tab, the table is not showing. But if I mouse click ANYWHERE on the web page, it shows the table. (its as if the web page is being 'refreshed' via a mouse click after the JQuery function. Anyone know about this? and suggestions on how to fix?

Regards,

Comment: #tabs-2 is basically a div with standard JQuery CSS. Basically myTable is within #tabs-2.

Comment: btw this works for #tabs-1, but i'm not physically adding the event to #tabs-1, as the page loads, all required data is loaded in #tabs-1, and I dont want to automatically load data into #tabs-2 because it might be necessary and will cause performance issues. So i figured that I could add a Click event to #tabs-2 to display data in that tab.

Comment: Some more info: I see if i take out the click event on #tab-2, and only have the .ajax function inside the document.ready function all data is showing correctly. So it must be something with the #tabs-2 and the way the page is being shown and generated by JQuery... :(